# Cyclical Dependency Error in ProxyStore

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs6

I am trying to solve a tricky bug at the momentin extjs6. I get an infinite loop while saving a record in the ProxyStore :

> Ext.JSON.doEncode     ext-all-debug.js:48683
>
> Ext.JSON.encodeObject @   ext-all-debug.js:48789
>
> Ext.JSON.doEncode @   ext-all-debug.js:48685
>
> Ext.JSON.encodeObject @   ext-all-debug.js:48789

Upon further investigation I found that if I save a row in a table for a second time then the data objects in my table are being polluted with some strange methods.

Initially I have in my store data (eg **store.data.items[0].data**) an entry like this :

```
{autoRelease: false
id: "app.model.DssMarketModel-9"
foo: "1"
bar: "2"}
```

If I open this in a dialog and a **Ext.form.Panel**, I can modify this object and save it. After I have saved it however, the record becomes polluted with a whole bunch of junk after I perform a 'synch' on the proxy store (ie. **Ext.data.ProxyStore sync()**).

```
{
getAllResponseHeaders: ()
getResponseHeader: (name)
request: constructor
getAllResponseHeaders: ()
getResponseHeader: (name)
////
autoRelease: "false"
id: "app.model.DssMarketModel-9"
foo: "1"
bar: "2"
////
request: constructor
requestId: 9
responseText: ""
responseXML: null
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
}
```

This causes my stack overflow cyclical dependency problem, because deep in the request object there is a reference to the same record object again, making synching impossible.

It appears that these new properties have been put there via something called **app.overrides.ResponseHeadersBugfix** .

Would anyone know why this problem could be happening? And why would the ResponseHeadersBugFix properties attach themselves to my table records?